# SQL ORDER BY multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
  id, name
FROM
  data
ORDER BY
  FIELD(id, 4, 5, 8, 10) DESC,
  name
```

Ids `4, 5, 8, 10` are up top. So far so good. But then I want to sort by `name`. This doesn't work. Did maybe `FIELD` already determined a specific order? Can I change the SQL so I can still tell SQL what ids should be up top (in a true/falsy relation) but do the final ordering by name? Some kind of enum?

The ids in `FIELD(id, 4, 5, 8, 10)` came from another source. They represent if there is data to given id in the foreign source.

Comment: which DB do you use ?

Comment: What if you change the order like `ORDER BY name,  FIELD(id, 4, 5, 8, 10)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use ANSI 92 Compatible [`CASE WHEN`](http://www.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/#33399.htm) like this.

```
SELECT
  id, name
FROM
  data
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN id IN (4, 5, 8, 10) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
  name
```

Comment: No Problem, Always mention your RDBMS in your question. you'll get quicker and accurate answers

Comment: Side note: FIELD does something different but maybe in OP's case _this_ is what he was trying to achive

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - You are absolutely correct. if OP wanted to define separate order priority of each of these ids, `FIELD` is the best candidate